# DiffUtils do not display new items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

`DiffUtils.dispatchUpdatesTo(adapter)` not updating the size of my array in `recyclerView`

my `result` has size more than current `itemList`, but displays only current size

How to display changes in size of my array by `DiffUtils` ? I think use `notifyDatasetChanged()` is not correct.

Here's how i do this now in adapter:

```
    fun update(items: List<ITEM>) {
    updateAdapterWithDiffResult(calculateDiff(items))
}

private fun updateAdapterWithDiffResult(result: DiffUtil.DiffResult) {
    result.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
}

private fun calculateDiff(newItems: List<ITEM>) =
        DiffUtil.calculateDiff(DiffUtilCallback(itemList, newItems))
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your list size is not updating, because you are not adding new items in your **itemList**

update your code like this-

```
class YourAdapter(
    private val itemList: MutableList<ITEM>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

.
.
.

    fun updateList(newList: MutableList<ITEM>) {
        val diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(
                DiffUtilCallback(this.itemList, newList))

        itemList.clear()
        itemList.addAll(newList)

        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }
}
```

hope it will work for you.

Comment: Yes, it works, but why diffutils don't do it by itself?

Comment: because probably you implemented the function getItemCount() according to your list itemList , and diffUtils can not change the content of the function by itself, and you should do that by yourself. Maybe in in the future the Google devs will change the structure of Adapter taking into account the diffutils

Comment: It is definitely better practice that DiffUtil doesn't change your implementation or list contents, that would go against immutability rules.

Comment: @SirojiddinKomolov doesn't `itemList.clear()` `itemList.addAll(newList)` do the same thing as `notifyDataSetChanged()` ? whats the need to use DiffUtil then?